# Howcome when I run my code, does it infinitely repeat the same statement?

Tags: javascript

I am writing code to make a guessing game with parameters as follows: [Guessing Game Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flwZ5.png). Could someone please help me figure out why when I run it, it constantly outputs the same two lines infinitely and doesn't give me an opportunity to guess again? Below is the code that I have written.

```
var randNum = Math.random() * (50 - 0) + 0;
var userGuess = prompt ("Choose a number between 1 and 50: ");
var count = 0;
var controlNum = 0;

while (userGuess != randNum){ 
  if (userGuess == randNum) {
    controlNum = 1
    console.log ("YOU GOT IT!");
    console.log (count);
  } else if (userGuess > randNum) {
    console.log ("TOO HIGH");
    console.log ("Try Agian");
    count ++
  } else if (userGuess < randNum) {
    console.log ("TOO LOW");
    console.log ("Try Again");
    count ++
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the prompt to choose a number outside of your while loop.

Therefore, userGuess never actually changes, and it keeps comparing userGuess to randNum. That's an infinite loop (unless you get it right the first time).

Try this:

```
var randNum = Math.random() * (50 - 0) + 0;
var userGuess = 0;
var count = 0;
var controlNum = 0;

while (userGuess != randNum){ 
userGuess = prompt ("Choose a number between 1 and 50: ");
  if (userGuess == randNum) {
    controlNum = 1
    console.log ("YOU GOT IT!");
    console.log (count);
  } else if (userGuess > randNum) {
    console.log ("TOO HIGH");
    console.log ("Try Agian");
    count ++
  } else if (userGuess < randNum) {
    console.log ("TOO LOW");
    console.log ("Try Again");
    count ++
  }
}
```

Comment: No problem, Also, just noticed you didn't round your random number, so (unless I'm missing something) they're never going to be equal

Comment: replace with:
`var randNum = (Math.random() * 50).ceil()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) will give you number in `floating-point` pseudo-random number in the range 0 to less than 1. So you need to get the `int` part only.

Second You need to ask the user to guess again so you need to `prompt` again after checking all condition

```js
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 0) + 0);
var userGuess = prompt("Choose a number between 1 and 50: ");
var count = 0;
var controlNum = 0;

while (userGuess != randNum) {
  if (userGuess == randNum) {
    controlNum = 1;
    console.log("YOU GOT IT!");
    console.log(count);
  } else if (userGuess > randNum) {
    console.log("TOO HIGH");
    console.log("Try Agian");
    count++;
  } else if (userGuess < randNum) {
    console.log("TOO LOW");
    console.log("Try Again");
    count++;
  }
  userGuess = prompt("Choose a number between 1 and 50: ");
}
```